# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel' when punning py script from collab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Google Collab returns following error when i try to run .py script from collab.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

Here is my code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!python drive/My\ Drive/reader.py
```

And Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/пэ_reader.py", line 28, in <module>
    drive.mount('/content/drive')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py", line 103, in mount
    return _mount(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py", line 132, in _mount
    _message.blocking_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py", line 173, in blocking_request
    request_id = send_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py", line 117, in send_request
    instance = ipython.get_kernelapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/colab/_ipython.py", line 28, in get_kernelapp
    return get_ipython().kernel.parent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

I`ve also tried with files upload, but no luck as well.

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
!python '/content/reader.py'
```

Comment: Apparently, `get_ipython()` is `None`

Comment: No, get_ipython().__class__.__name__ returns Shell :)